# accessing form elements from a class

Tags: c#, winforms

i was trying to make this code:

```
        public void _open_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _playList.Items.Clear();
        _openFile.Multiselect = true;
        _openFile.Filter = "Mp3 Files|*.mp3|Avi Files|*.avi|Mp4 Files|*.mp4";
        _openFile.ShowDialog();
        doc = _openFile.SafeFileNames;
        path = _openFile.FileNames;
        for (int i = 0; i < doc.Length; i++)
        {
            _playList.Items.Add(doc[i]);
        }
    }
```

from a class
so i created a class called mplayer
and then an instance of the form
and put all that code in there

what suppose to happen is when i click a button
file dialog opens
and all selected song names would go into a listbox
for some reason it doesn't open and no compilation nor exception errors pops
please advise

Comment: Is the click handler of the form element correctly assigned to your method?

Comment: im kind of new to this. is the fact that from inside the form code it works means that the handler is correctly assigned?

Comment: { // _open
            // 
            resources.ApplyResources(this._open, "_open");
            this._open.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this._open.Image = global::PhoenixDownloader.Properties.Resources.open_file_icon;
            this._open.Name = "_open";
            this._open.TabStop = false;
            this._open.Click += new System.EventHandler(this._open_Click_1); }      this is the handler it seems ok i think. right?

Comment: What if you create a `new OpenFileDialog()` instead of using `_openFile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see the event handler is correctly assigned. Btw try this code, it is working in my project:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _open.Click += new EventHandler(_open_Click_1);
    }

    private void _open_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
        _playList.Items.Clear();
        _openFile.Multiselect = true;
        _openFile.Filter = "Mp3 Files|*.mp3|Avi Files|*.avi|Mp4 Files|*.mp4";
        _openFile.ShowDialog();
        var doc = _openFile.SafeFileNames;
        var path = _openFile.FileNames;
        for (int i = 0; i < doc.Length; i++)
        {
            _playList.Items.Add(doc[i]);
        }
    }
```

Note: I was using local variables for the selected file names and path.

Answer (score 0):

maybe i wasn't explaining myself very well. im trying to call a class which does that. like this

```
public static class mplayer
{
    public static void openMusic()
    {
        PhoenixDownloader.searchForm frm = new searchForm();
        frm._playlist.items.clear();
        frm._openfile.multiselect = true;
        frm._openfile.filter = "mp3 files|*.mp3|avi files|*.avi|mp4 files|*.mp4";
        frm._openfile.showdialog();
        frm.doc = frm._openfile.safefilenames;
        frm.path = frm._openfile.filenames;
        for (int i = 0; i < frm.doc.length; i++)
        {
            frm._playlist.items.add(frm.doc[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

and on the event part:

```
        public void _open_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mplayer();
    }
```

and it it doesn't happen